# How to remove all misspelled words from text file?

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I'm trying to create a proper word list of about 22,000 words, but a vast majority of them are misspelled.

I need to find a way to mark all misspelled > remove all marked lines

or just remove anything considered a misspelled word and replace with nothing.

Only troubleshooting I'm finding are people who are trying to remove misspelled words from the Spellcheck Dictionary.

Any thoughts?

P.S. Here is a GIF Image of me showing the long process I'm trying to shortcut:

https://gyazo.com/0842873c3ffebd502916b016843b5f92

Answer (score 1):

In Linux:  `comm -23 in.txt <(aspell list < in.txt) > out.txt`.
(In Windows, instead of Notepad++, type that command in a Linux shell such as [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)).

The `aspell` command lists the misspelled words.
The `comm` command then prints only those words in `in.txt` that were missing from aspell's output.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you simply copy part by part of the text to the MS word, or what ever office you have. Then simply remove the misspelled words and save the new copy ?

Comment: Well i know this is not what you are looking for but it is simply an idea

Comment: Even in Word he still need to delete them one by one, how is it improved compared to current process in the question?

Comment: I've tried this, I even used an Autoclicker with a 1ms click to autofill the suggestions on spell check and removed the duplicates.

It didn't prove to do much and I can't find where you can remove a mass of misspelled words in Word? If you can do this, can you clarify and show me?

I searched for a bit on how to remove all misspelled words in Microsoft Word and didn't find any results...

Comment: Well, we all actually want the computer to do our dirty work, so pls at least tell me what operation system you are using?